# Problemas com retorno/escopo em CoffeeScript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Tenho no Rails uma rota `get '/estados_por_pais/:pais_id` que me retorna um array JSON com estados deste pais. Isto funciona perfeitamente.

Criei uma classe CoffeeScript com um método estático que deveria buscar retornar este array de estados:

```
class window.Municipio

  @busca_estados_por_pais: (pais_id) ->
    retorno = 1
    $.get "/estados_por_pais/#{ pais_id }", (estados) ->
      retorno = estados
      #debug
      alert estados
      alert retorno
      return
    retorno
```

Aqui a saída Javascript:

```
(function() {
  window.Municipio = (function() {
    function Municipio() {}

    Municipio.busca_estados_por_pais = function(pais_id) {
      var retorno;
      retorno = 1;
      $.get("/estados_por_pais/" + pais_id, function(estados) {
        retorno = estados;
        alert(estados);
        alert(retorno);
      });
      return retorno;
    };

    return Municipio;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

Neste caso as saídas de `alert(estados)` e `alert(retorno)` é exatamente a esperada, ou seja, um array de objetos.

Porém o retorno do método é `1`, sendo que a variável `retorno` não está sendo redeclarada dentro do escopo da função do jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que `$.get` é uma função assíncrona, e por isso o seu método `busca_estados_por_pais` retorna antes que o resultado da requisição ajax chegue. A solução mais recomendada é reestruturar seu código para usar callbacks:

```
class window.Municipio

  @busca_estados_por_pais: (pais_id, callback) ->
    $.get "/estados_por_pais/#{ pais_id }", (estados) ->
      callback(estados)
```

Na chamada do método, você vai precisar passar uma função (o callback) que será executada quando o resultado da requisição estiver disponível.

Comment: O callback  é mesmo recomendado. Outra alternativa seria fazer a requisição de forma síncrona, porém isso "travaria" o browser. (Pesquisei rapidamente sobre isso depois da sua resposta) =)